# Persistent Volume Claim Kubernetes

Tags: linux, kubernetes, diskspace, persistent-volumes

`Kubectl version` gives the following output.

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.4", GitCommit:"b695d79d4f967c403a96986f1750a35eb75e75f1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-11-17T15:48:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.5", GitCommit:"aea7bbadd2fc0cd689de94a54e5b7b758869d691", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-09-15T21:04:16Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I have used `kubectl` to edit persistent volume from 8Gi to 30Gi as [image]

However, when I exec the pod and run `df -h` I see the following:

[image]

I have deleted the pods but it again shows the same thing. if I `cd` into `cd/dev` I don't see disk and `vda1` folder there as well. I think I actually want the `bitnami/influxdb` to be 30Gi. Please guide and let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: Did you manually edit both the PV and PVC? (If so, see warning here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#expanding-persistent-volumes-claims )

Comment: It may also depends on whether your storage technology supports volume expansion.

Comment: Yes i edited it directly, may be using helm chart was better option.

Comment: @SamiHassan Please provide more details about your environment: what cluster type is used, which kubernetes version is used? Also as Rakesh mentioned not all PVs can be expended. See [kubernetes documentation pvc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#expanding-persistent-volumes-claims)

Comment: @moonkotte i have added cluster info as well it is provisioned on digital ocean

Comment: @SamiHassan Did you read about volume expansion? We provided the link two times here. It just looks that digital ocean storage does not support `allowVolumeExpansion` flag. You need to try it.

Answer (score 1):

*This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.*

Based on the comments provided here, there could be several reasons for this behavior.

1. According to the documentation from the [Kubernetes website](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#expanding-persistent-volumes-claims), manually changing the PersistentVolume size will not change the volume size:

> **Warning:** Directly editing the size of a PersistentVolume can prevent
> an automatic resize of that volume. If you edit the capacity of a
> PersistentVolume, and then edit the .spec of a matching
> PersistentVolumeClaim to make the size of the PersistentVolumeClaim
> match the PersistentVolume, then no storage resize happens. The
> Kubernetes control plane will see that the desired state of both
> resources matches, conclude that the backing volume size has been
> manually increased and that no resize is necessary.

1. It also depends on how Kubernetes running and support for the `allowVolumeExpansion` feature. From [DigitalOcean](https://github.com/digitalocean/csi-digitalocean/issues/291#issuecomment-598783816):

> are you running one of DigitalOcean's managed clusters, or a DIY
> cluster running on DigitalOcean infrastructure? In case of the latter,
> which version of our CSI driver do you use? (You need v1.2.0 or later
> for volume expansion to be supported.)